# Recycle bin in Windows start menu search

Tags: windows-7, start-menu, windows-search

Is there some way to add a Recycle Bin entry to the Windows start menu's search?

[[image: Screenshot of search]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PorKR.png)

Note I'm asking for something that will come up at the top when a part of `Recycle Bin` is typed, e.g. `Recy`. I am aware of `shell:RecycleBinFolder` - which also happens to be recognised under the `Internet` category.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find Recycle bin in start menu search as you asked is explained very detailed [here with screen caps.](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/13105/add-the-recycle-bin-to-start-menu-in-windows-7/)
Hope that post useful to you.I have tried in my comp and it works like follows.

- In My computer or Windows explorer type these in navigation toolbar C:\Users\Desingh(**type your user name**)\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
  [image]
- Right click, create  new shortcut and enter this

  > explorer.exe shell:RecycleBinFolder

  And name the shortcut as " Recycle Bin" and click finish
  [image]
  [image]
  [image]

Now type Recy in search bar it will show the Recycle Bin shortcut link 
It shows me like this.
If you want to change the icon of Recycle Bin link you can do it by the procedure given above link but not necessary .

[image]

Comment: I see, I tried that before but did not realise a shortcut required passing the shell link to `explorer.exe`, i.e. I had tried a shortcut to just `shell:RecycleBinFolder` which obviously did not work. Would you mind adding at least a brief version of those instructions to your answer?